# Can't select from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have following database:

[image]

I want to select all columns from 'catalog' table. Used this code, but it doesn't work.

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'technomart') or die('No Connection');

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM catalog';

$res = mysqli_query($link, $sql);




while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    print_r($row);
```

Comment: you have closed your connection before you fetched your data.

Comment: Then you throw away the result of the query i.e. `mysqli_close($link);` before you try and read all the results.

Comment: `'SELECT * FROM orders'`, also you closed connection, keep `mysqli_close();` after u done with the data from db, even you can leave it.

Comment: It was my mistake, I meant 'catalog table'.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is not the closing connection command. I've removed it from code, doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You state:

> I want to select all columns from 'catalog' table.

But your code as displayed says:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM orders';
```

Replace the name `orders` with `catalog` and you will then be dealing with the data on that table.

syntax:

> ```
> $sql = SELECT <columns>[, <columns>] FROM <table>
> ```

---

As stated by [Biswajit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39686905/3536236) you are also closing your connection before you are returning your data. You should not need to close the connection until the very end of the page.

Comment: I meant 'catalog' table, sorry. Anyway, the problem is not the closing connection command. I've removed it from code, doesn't work anyway.

Comment: @Dre ok try this: `$res = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));` = error output, if no error output then your SQL works fine and the issue is your table of data is empty ( nothing to output)

Answer (score 1):

You are closing connection before fetching data from database. use `mysqli_close($link);` after your while loop.

Comment: what is the error? if you doesn't find any error follow the link to generate error http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp